# WiFi HaLow library

Tags: wifi, library

Does anyone know if some Arduino based library is on the way to support new low power WiFi HaLow modules. If there is, I would like to know for which module?

For reference I'm sharing link [here](https://www.wi-fi.org/discover-wi-fi/wi-fi-certified-halow)

Comment: What's a WiFi HaLow module?

Comment: I shared link in the question

Comment: If anyone will make one Adafruit will, and they haven't yet. The tech is too new for Arduino...